# Node.js Passport deserializing Users returns 20+ identical users

Tags: node.js, facebook, parse-platform, passport.js

Everything seems to works. The request to [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) checks if the users exists and either creates it or retrieves it.
I'm having two main problem. First, when the `deserializeUser` function is called it returns 20 identical users and the `findUser` function, as it should, returns those 20 users.
Also, I can't access the `req.user`

```
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

            done(null, user.objectId);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(uid, done) {

            console.log(uid)
            // This outputs the ObjectId 20 TIMES!! ??

            Parse.findUser(uid,function(error,user){

                done(null, user);
            })
    });

    // CONFIGURATION
    app.configure(function() {
            app.use(express.bodyParser()); //read
            app.use(express.cookieParser()); //read
        app.use(express.session({ secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'abcde' }));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());
            app.use(app.router);
            app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))
    });

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID || 'app_id',
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET || 'fb_secret',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook/callback"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            process.nextTick(function() {
                    _parse.user(accessToken, profile,function(parseUser){
                        //this returns the user.....

                    return done(null, parseUser);
                    })
            })
        })
    )
    app.get('/auth/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook',{scope:'email'}),
            function(req, res){
                // The request will be redirected to Facebook ....
    });

    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
            function(req, res) {

                    console.log(req.user)
                    // this works! ...
                res.redirect('/browse');
    });

    app.get('/browse',function(req,res){
            console.log(req.user)
            // this is works too ...

            res.render('browse.jade',{title:'Browse',classes:'browse'})
    })

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

Comment: What Parse library are you using? That doesn't look like the official Parse JavaScript SDK.

Comment: The javascript SDK is for the client, i haven't tried it on the server but i'm pretty sure it doesn't work (somebody correct me if I'm wrong)... i'm using [this module](https://github.com/tenorviol/node-parse-api) which successfully returns the user from Parse.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using the official JavaScript API provided by Parse.com at http://parse.com/docs/downloads ?

Comment: I'm using [this node package](https://github.com/Leveton/node-parse-api) from the docs. `Parse.getUser` is actually `Parse.findUser`, i don't know why i changed it now... i updated it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are loading a page with 20 different resources, and each call is for a single request to one of those resources.

Move the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))` middleware to the top of your middleware stack.  Since those resources are static and public, its not necessary to parse the body, cookies or load sessions.

Comment: THANKS!!! Awesome, it works! So, what was I doing exactly? Why is the order important?

Comment: The request will pass through the middleware in the order they are listed, until one of them sends a response.  Static middleware responds immediately, skipping any dynamic behavior like authentication.

Comment: This is no longer working for me. I have passportjs all the way on the bottom before the routes and it makes deserialise calls everytime i request some of my assets. anyone else experiencing the same thing?